# Showing / hiding content based on route in Angular, only works after refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-show

I have a header + footer I don't want to show on the landing (language) page. This works, but only after a refresh. What would be best practice to solve this?

Here's what I've got:

```
<div ng-include= " 'includes/header.html ' " ng-show="{{currentPage != '/language'}}">
```

Inside my LanguageCtrl there's

`$scope.currentPage = $location.path() === "/language";`

I assign the controllers with ui-router $stateProvider like this:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: "/",
            data: {
                rule: function($cookieStore) {
                                if ($cookieStore.get('languageCookie')) {
                                        return {
                                            toState: 'home'
                                        }
                    }

                                 else return {
                                        toState: 'language',
                                        toParams: {}
                                };
                        }
            },
            controller: "HomeCtrl",
            templateUrl: "view/home.html"
        })
        .state('language', {
            url: "/language",
            controller: "languageCtrl",
            templateUrl: "view/language.html"
        })
```

note: this is not fully functional yet.

How can I make this work without the need to refresh? 
Do I need to put this inside .run function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

controller on body

```
<body ng-controller="routeCtrl">
```

ng-show if the state is not language

```
<div ng-include=" 'includes/header.html ' " ng-show="!state.includes('language')"></div>
```

controller:

```
 .controller('routeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$state', function($scope, $location, $state) {
    $scope.state = $state;
 }]);`
```

So now the header doesn't get included on the language page.

Answer (score 0):

It only assigns the value once, you should watch for changes or use a method to return the value

```
<div ng-include="'includes/header.html'" ng-show="{{!isCurrentPage('/language')}}">
```

controller

```
$scope.isCurrentPage = function(path) {
   return path == $location.path();
}
```

Comment: This is probably it, thanks. Where should I put the isCurrentPage function so that it gets executed every time? Inside homeCtrl or languageCtrl it doesn't get executed.

Comment: For me to answer that you should show a bit more of your code. Could you show your html and controller code. Where do you assign the controller?

Comment: I assign the controllers with ui-router $stateProvider, I added some $stateProvider code. I think the problem is these controller only get executed on the corresponding pageview. Would I need a place in the code that gets executed every time?

Comment: what view is "<div ng-include= " 'includes/header.html ' " ng-show="{{currentPage != '/language'}}">
" in?  ah, I see you managed to solve it already :)

Comment: yes, thanks for the suggestion though. My solution works, but I'm not sure what's best practice/performance.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I found so far.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            template: "<h1>Home</h1>"
        })
        .state('contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            template: "<h1>Contact</h1>"
        });
});

app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $location, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState){

        $rootScope.showInclude = true;

        if($state.current.name === 'contact') {
            $rootScope.showInclude = false;
        }
    });
});
```

**Your include**

```
<div ng-include="'include.html'" ng-if="showInclude"></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/pUUjhfMGKWxdwO8ENjaD?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isState` or `includedByState` filters to handle this all in the view.